# How to create associative array in Yii2 and convert to JSON?

Tags: json, yii2

I am using a calendar in my project and I want to pass data from my `Event` model to view file in `JSON` format. I tried following but it didn't work and am not able to display the data properly

```
$events = Event::find()->where(1)->all();

$data = [];

foreach ($events AS $model){
    //Testing
    $data['title'] = $time->title;
    $data['date'] = $model->start_date;
    $data['description'] = $time->description;
}

\Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
echo \yii\helpers\Json::encode($data);
```

But it only returns one model in that `$data` array, the final data should be in  following format:

```
[
    {"date": "2013-03-19 17:30:00", "type": "meeting", "title": "Test Last Year" },
    { "date": "2013-03-23 17:30:00", "type": "meeting", "title": "Test Next Year" }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write this:

```
\Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
```

before rendering data, there is no need to do any additional manipulations for converting array to JSON.

You just need to `return` (not `echo`) an array:

```
return $data;
```

An array will be automatically transformed to JSON.

Also it's better to use `yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON` constant instead of hardcoded string.

Another way of handling that will be using [ContentNegotiator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-contentnegotiator.html) filter which has more options, allows setting of multiple actions, etc. Example for controller:

```
use yii\web\Response;

...

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\filters\ContentNegotiator',
            'only' => ['view', 'index'],  // in a controller
            // if in a module, use the following IDs for user actions
            // 'only' => ['user/view', 'user/index']
            'formats' => [
                'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
            ],                
        ],
    ];
}
```

It can also be configured for whole application.

**Update:** If you are using it outside of controller, don't set response format. Using `Json` helper with `encode()` method should be enough. But there is also one error in your code, you should create new array element like this:

```
$data = [];
foreach ($events as $model) {
    $data[] = [
        'title' => $time->title,
        'date' => $model->start_date,
        'description' => $time->description,
    ];
}
```

Comment: actually thats not it. I tried that but didnt work as i need to echo the output in json format so that plugin on frontpage can display it.

Comment: @arogachev: Very well explained! I didn't knew about ContentNegotiator filter. Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
$events = Event::find()->select('title,date,description')->where(1)->all()
yii::$app->response->format = yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON; // Change response format on the fly

return $events; // return events it will automatically be converted in JSON because of the response format.
```

Btw you are overwriting `$data` variable in `foreach` loop you should do:

```
$data = [];
foreach ($events AS $model){
    //Make a multidimensional array
    $data[] = ['time' => $time->title,'date' => $model->start_date,'description' => $time->description];
}
echo \yii\helpers\Json::encode($data);
```

Comment: How it's different from my answer? I mentioned all these details and even more.